# How to index the MongoDB "id_" field with Elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch with MongoDB and want to search for ObjectIDs in my Elasticsearch Index.

My MongoDB contains entries like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ca06664ceb6693d37de155"), "blabla" : "xxxyyy"}
```

I tried to create a custom mapping for example:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/myIndex/myType/_mapping" -d'
{
"myType":{
  "properties":{
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": true,
      "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "blabla": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": true,
      "index": "analyzed"
    }
}
```

}'

but when I want to check my mappings with

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_mapping'
```

I can't see the _id mapping. Searching for "54ca06664ceb6693d37de155" also does not return any results.

What's wrong?

Comment: How are you loading data from MongoDB into Elasticsearch? Did you create this mapping before you loaded any data?

Comment: I'm using River (https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb). First I create the Index, then I create the Mapping and at last I create the River. It works fine for the other fields but unfortunately not for the "_id"_ field.

Answer (score 0):

_id field is default primary key in Elasticsearch like mongoDB.Though you dont find mapping for _id field, you can search for _id field using below query. for more info [refer this link.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html)

You can find _id field in returns documents:

```
 {
"_index" :   "website",
"_type" :    "blog",
"_id" :      "123",
"_version" : 1,
"found" :    true,
"_source" :  {
  "title": "My first blog entry",
  "text":  "Just trying this out...",
  "date":  "2014/01/01"
 }
}
```

**QUERY 1:**

```
{
"query": {
    "terms": {
       "_id": [
          "VALUE1",
          "VALUE2"
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
       "_id": {
          "value": "VALUE"
          }
       }
    }
}
```